# How to get the total points from my database using MySQL and the SUM function?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Please see below my code i have created to generate the data from my database:

```
SELECT customerorderdetails.OrderDate,Discount,Quantity, products.ProductName,
       ProductCost,Points FROM customerorderdetails 
INNER JOIN products ON  products.ProductID=customerorderdetails.ProductID
```

---

```
 OrderDate  Discount    Quantity    ProductName     ProductCost     Points  
2015-09-01  10              2        Milk            0.50             5
2015-09-01  10              2         Mild Cheese    2.00             6
2015-09-01  10              1        Edam Cheese     2.10             5
2015-09-01  10              1        Eggs            1.00             3
2015-09-01  10              2        Butter          1.00             2
2015-09-01  10              2        Eggs             1.00            3
```

I now need to to create a mysql query to add all the points together made.
i have tried the below code to no affect.

```
SELECT SUM customerorderdetails.OrderDate,Discount,Quantity, 
products.ProductName,ProductCost,Points, 
FROM customerorderdetails
INNER JOIN products
ON products.ProductID=customerorderdetails.ProductID
WHERE customerorderdetails.ProductName=''
AND customerorderdetails.OrderDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-9-04'
AND products.ProductName=''
```

I then changed the code to the below but now get error 1064,

```
SELECT customerorderdetails.OrderDate,Discount,Quantity,
 products.ProductName,ProductCost,Points,
FROM customerorderdetails
INNER JOIN products
ON products.ProductID=customerorderdetails.ProductID
AND customerorderdetails.OrderDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-9-04'
SELECT SUM(Points) FROM products
```

Comment: Do you need to add points for all products only ?

Comment: Yes. all products purchased from BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-9-04'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT  customerorderdetails.OrderDate,SUM(Discount) AS Discount ,SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, 
products.ProductName,SUM(ProductCost) AS ProductCost,SUM(Points)  AS Points, 
FROM customerorderdetails
INNER JOIN products
ON products.ProductID=customerorderdetails.ProductID
WHERE customerorderdetails.OrderDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-9-04'
GROUP BY customerorderdetails.ProductID
```